# How to disable text chat in Source engine games?

Tags: source-engine

Given that the [Source engine console command set](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Console_Command_List) is so extensive, is there a command to disable text chat? I feel that text chat is commonly used for trolling and harassment, as voice chat has a higher barrier for such behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `hud_saytext_time 0` in `autoexec.cfg` (in-game console may also work), likely located in `cfg` folder.  Create the file if it doesn't exist.

Note: While this "generally" works, the developer can likely disable the command, or text chat altogether.
You are still able to send and view messages by manually opening chat window (see keybinds)—technically the chat log is only hidden from view.

> `hud_saytext_time` is a console command which changes the amount of
>   time that text shown in the chat box stays visible for, before fading.
>
> **Usage**
>   Syntax: `hud_saytext_time <integer>` (in seconds).
>
> The default value is 12 seconds.

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Hud_saytext_time